# Reversal frames in video editor seem to not be working properly in 2.92

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am attempting to toggle the reverse frames option in the video-editor like I have in the past. Checking the box seems to neither reverse the frames, nor anything else related, but it does add a random frame or two from the source folder at a random time in the reversed frames.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Comment: can you please show us a screenshot which checkbox you are checking?

Comment: He's checking the _Reverse Frames_ checkbox, of course ;) This might be a bug. In my 2.83 version it's working as expected, but in 2.92 it's doing strange things. But only in playback mode, when I start rendering it it works.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in all my Blender versions now, 2.83.5, 2.92.0, 2.93.0 Beta and 3.0.0 Alpha. Only 2.92.0 and 3.0.0 showed strange playback behaviour. But I could make it work by going to the first frame (which should be the last since it's reversed), then hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to render a still frame, which correctly displayed the last image. After doing this render, the playback worked as well.